# How to properly use RecyclerView and caching for best performance and avoid having micro-lag on first scrolls

Tags: android, android-layout, caching, android-recyclerview

I want to know what I can do to maximise RecyclerView performance when having extensive data and media resources. I have literally tried almost every solution I found on google's first 3 pages of search results, every Medium article on the topic, it changed nothing.

On any phone I tested my app, I get this micro-lag or micro-stutter when I first scroll the recyclerView and then everything flows smooth. But the first scroll always has this annoying lag. It happens on all 3 different recyclerView lists in my app as well as a ViewPager2 activity that is based on a recyclerView adapter.

So, more specific details: I code in Kotlin, use Retrofit/Okhttp for networking, Room for local database and I do download all the data in the Splash Screen, including caching the images with Glide without displaying them anywhere. Basically the recyclerViews must only get the data from Room and display it in the list while Glide takes the images from the cache and displays them in every image view.

Still, the app lags when I scroll for the first time. In the past, it used to lag constantly because I was downloading the images with glide only inside the viewHolders and obviously the recyclerView scroll was bricking every time a new image was being downloaded and displayed. After I cached the images in Splash Screen, the only lag that occurs is the one on the first scroll, the rest is smooth as silk.

Tried many tutorials like a pre caching custom layout manager like:

```
    public class PreCachingLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private static final int DEFAULT_EXTRA_LAYOUT_SPACE = 600;
    private int extraLayoutSpace = -1;
    private Context context;

    public PreCachingLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public PreCachingLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int extraLayoutSpace) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.extraLayoutSpace = extraLayoutSpace;
    }

    public PreCachingLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setExtraLayoutSpace(int extraLayoutSpace) {
        this.extraLayoutSpace = extraLayoutSpace;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getExtraLayoutSpace(RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (extraLayoutSpace > 0) {
            return extraLayoutSpace;
        }
        return DEFAULT_EXTRA_LAYOUT_SPACE;
    }
}
```

and then `layoutManager.setExtraLayoutSpace(2 * SharedPreferences.deviceScreenHeight)`

or various settings like cache size, etc.

```
homepageAdapter.setHasStableIds(true)
    rvMainBoxList.apply {
        adapter = homepageAdapter
        isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
        hasFixedSize()
        setItemViewCacheSize(30)
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager
    }
```

Tried simplifying my XML codes by getting rid of all the Constraint Layouts, setting fixed heights to all resources, removing al useless parents, etc. Nothing happened, the recycler still lags the first time you scroll.

Any out of the box ideas on how to fix this would help me a lot!

This is my adapter:

```
class ItemAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_row))
    }

    var items: List<Item> = ArrayList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            this.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    var onClickListener: ((Item) -> (Unit))? = null

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        fun bind(item: Item) {
            setData(item)
            setControls(item)
        }

        private fun setData(item: Item) {
            val view: View = itemView.rootView
            // Set data here
            }
        }

        private fun setControls(item: Item) {
            itemView.rlLoginItemContainer.setOnClickListener {
                onClickListener?.invoke(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should post your Adapter code so we can get a better idea how you're going about this.

My suspicion is that you may be doing your Room call in your ViewHolder and this is blocking the creation of your view by a brief moment.  Since each ViewHolder is only created the first time you scroll past an item you would only see the lag on the first scroll down.  After that, all the data is in memory and RecyclerView is just swapping out the data into the views it can fit on screen as you scroll around.

If you are doing the Room call in the adapter at all I would really recommend looking into the Jetpack Library called PagedList.  This would handle paging the data from your Room database into your RecyclerView more efficiently.  Google has a great sample app on their GitHub page that shows them doing network calls that cache into a Room database as a user scrolls through a RecyclerView using this.  If you wanted to fully commit to it you could probably move all of that loading out of your splash screen.

Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Example code:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample

Good luck!

Comment: Hi. I have updated the question with the adapter code. No I do not do any Room calls there, the room calls happen only in the repository. In my activity I just observe the viewModel list and set it to the adapter when it comes !=0. The issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Change from 600 to private static final int DEFAULT_EXTRA_LAYOUT_SPACE = 10000;
You will see smooth improve buts dangerous somehow if your layout doesn't have extra space